# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application gives LimitExceeded: PORTS error

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, port

I'm trying to deploy an application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I deployed app before using EBS but this time it's tricky.

Application uses 80 and 4000-4100 ports.

I am able to map port 80, but couldn't map other ports.

In docker-compose file ports are defined as a range;

```
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 4000-4100:4000-4100
```

Since I couldn't find how to map port ranges I gave port mapping one by one as follows;

```
{  
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
...      
     "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 8080,
          "hostPort": 80
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 4000,
          "containerPort": 4000
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 4001,
          "containerPort": 4001
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 4002,
          "containerPort": 4002
        },
...
```

but EBS gives following error;

```
Encountered error starting new ECS task: {
... eb-ecs: "failures": [
... eb-ecs: {
... eb-ecs: "reason": "LimitExceeded: PORTS",
```

How can I map these ports? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I could find is; reducing number of ports to 90.

In the future if we need more port, we can set forward rules based on the port number